# Query about SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have developed a database class which contains the utility methods like

1>Create a database

2>Create a table

3>Insert values into the table , etc

sample code

**(Creating the table):**

```
public void createTable(String createStmt, SQLiteDatabase sqlDB) {
    try {
        this.createStmt = createStmt;
        this.sqlDB = sqlDB;
        this.sqlDB.execSQL(createStmt);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

**(Deleting the table)**

```
public void deleteTable(String tableName) throws SQLiteException {
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.sqlDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
                + tableName + "'");
}
```

I am aware of the abstract class SQLiteOpenHelper  whose abstract methods like onCreate() & onUpgrade needs to be overriden .
I am calling my utility methods to createTable , insertTable & deleteTable from the UI code.

My question:

1. Is it necessary to extend the SQLiteOpenHelper ...it will be helpful for Upgrade ?
2. Will extending the SQLiteOpenHelper & then add my own utlity methods to the the class which extends SQliteOpenHelper be a good approach.

Kindly provide your inputs.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but SQL deletes rows using `DELETE FROM <tablename> WHERE <where clause>`. SQL "deletes" tables by dropping them, using `DROP TABLE <tablename>`.

Comment: Thanks Catcall for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short: Yes thats the way it should be done. Extending the SQliteOpenHelper is a good approach.